# How to insert two or multiple figures in a line?

Tags: subfloats

I want to insert two figures in the same lin, but it does not work. Here is my code-I used .arp class. Please help. Thanks

```
\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{subfigure}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Image/1.pdf}

\caption{xxxxxxxxxxxx}

\end{subfigure}{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Image/1.pdf}

\caption{yyyyyyyyyyyy}

\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Replace the blank line between the two sufigures with something like `\qquad` or `\hfill`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{xxxxxxxxxxxx}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{yyyyyyyyyyyy}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- Blank lines have their roles in LaTeX. Only add blank lines if necessary.
- Using `subcaption`, the environment `subfigure` has the following syntax

  ```
  \begin{subfigure}[float-option]{width}
  ...
  \end{subfigure}
  ```

  so your syntax is wrong.